# What is the difference between the #import "" (embedded header file) in the .h and .m files?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is an interview.

There are some answers existing：

1. Uses @Class in .h file is enough, and using #import ""  in .m file .
2. In header files referenced header file will at compile time is completely known file header information for all interface introduced, such as imported medical in A.H was future if import in the SubA.h A.h was, implicitly imported medical and increase unnecessary compilation, cohesion is low;
   In the implementation file header files, the compiler will only need to know the type of interface information, will reduce the compile time, and the degree of coupling between the classes will be reduced.

---

Can and how does one ask about this issue and What is the definitely guidelines ?

Comment: The question isn't clear.  Are you asking the difference between using `@class` and `#import` in a header file?

Comment: Not only，Can you explain more？

Comment: You have an answer already which looks fairly complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (maybe simplified) version goes like this:

If you import the header/interface file, it is like including the whole other file at that place. So typically all of your interface code is known at that place. When you are working with some classes/objects, the compiler needs to know what they are and how they are called exactly: what arguments/parameters do the methods need, what do the methods return? To answer these questions, the header files are usually included in the implmentation (.m) file.

As the implementation imports its own header file, you can often put the other imports just there. But when do you need the import in the header file? When you are declaring your interface, you often mention other types/classes, i.e. you say `@proerty (strong) SomeClass *element;`. Now the compiler needs to know *something* about SomeClass, but not all. If the compiler knows that it is another class, that will be ok at *this time*. In the header file, no more information is needed, so the "forward declaration" of `@class SomeClass` may suffice. Importing the complete header file for your other class works as well.

So where's the downside of import? There's mainly two arguments: compile time and import cycles. Consider the little example - whenever SomeClass.h changes, everything that includes it must be recompiled as well. This easily cascades through the complete code. Also, obviously, any code that imports your header file will import all their imports etc. The *cycles* arguments works like this. A.h imports B.h, B.h imports A.h. Depending on what's in them, one should be known before the other...

(I'd like to mention that the problems are a bit more relaxed with latest compilers but the basic argumentation still holds).

Some more notes: The @class forward declaration may be needed when you declare two types that relate to each other, i.e. a protocol that uses some class which you declare just below:

```
@class SomeClass;

@protocol SomeProtocol
-(void)doSomethingWith:(SomeClass *)object;
@end;

@interface SomeClass
@end
```

Forward declaration doesn't work for protocols the class implements or parent classes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer!   and can you talk about  more the difference between compiling and running in this question?

Comment: This is all about source and compilation. It won't have any effect on the running program at all.